# Simultaneous Quadratic Equations: $x^2 + y ^ 2 - 2 x + 6y - 35 = 0$ and $2x + 3y = 5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

I've been given the task to simultaneously solve:

$$x^2 + y ^ 2 - 2 x + 6y - 35 = 0$$

$$2x + 3y = 5$$

I've tried applying the substitution method by reordering the second equation to both $x$ and $y$, but both times I have got a surd.

According to the answers I should be getting $(-2, 3)$ and $(\frac{100}{13}, -\frac{45}{13})$, so evidently I am doing something wrong.

This is in the chapter `Equations Reducible to Quadratics` and I can not see how the material in the intro applies to the question.

Comment: Instead of just quotient the result (surd), try listing the process too so that we can find what went wrong.

Comment: You could probably find other questions for this type of problem (a system where one equation is quadratic and the other one is linear). For example [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599418/x2y2-1-5x12y13-0-simultaneous-equations). Maybe you will find a few more among questions taggged [systems-of-equations+quadratics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systems-of-equations+quadratics)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the second equation, we have that $x=\frac{5-3y}{2}$.  Plugging this into the first equation, 
$$\left(\frac{5-3y}{2}\right)^2+y^2-(5-3y)+6y-35=0\\
\frac{9y^2-30y+25}{4}+y^2+9y-40=0$$
Multiplying by $4$,
$$9y^2-30y+25+4y^2+36y-160=0\\
13y^2+6y-135=0$$
Applying the quadratic formula,
$$y=\frac{-6\pm\sqrt{6^2-4(13)(-135)}}{26}\\
=\frac{-6\pm84}{26}=\frac{-3\pm42}{13}=3,-\frac{45}{13}$$
Plugging these values back into our equation $x=\frac{5-3y}{2}$, we get solutions of $(2,-3)$, and $(\frac{100}{13},-\frac{45}{13}).$

Comment: Wow, this is the same method I used. I think the mistake was in the third step (I must have stuffed up the multiplication :P) Thank you!

Comment: haha it happens. Sure thing!

Answer (score 2):

By [completing the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) you can rewrite the first equation as
$$(x-1)^2+(y+3)^2=45.$$
So after the substitution $s=x-1$, $t=y+3$ you have new equations (which may be a bit simpler)
$$
\begin{align*}
s^2+t^2&=45\\
2s+3t&=12
\end{align*}
$$

This system of equations has a geometrical interpretation as intersection of a circle and a line. So you can draw a picture which might help you visualize the problem.

Now if you express $t=4-\frac23s$ from the second equation you get
$$t^2=16-\frac{16}3s+\frac49s^2.$$ 
Substituting this into the first equation you get
$$\frac{13}9s^2-\frac{16}3s-29=0\\
13s^2-48s-261=0$$

This quadratic equation [has two solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=13s%5E2-48s-261%3D0) $s=-3$ and $s=\frac{87}{13}$, which lead to $x=-2$ and $x=\frac{110}{13}$.
If you know values of $s$ and $x$, you can easily calculate $t$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

i will write the first equation as $$4x^2 + 4y^2 -8x + 24y -140 = 0 \tag 1$$ form the second equation, we have $$2x = 5 - 3y, 4x^2 = (5-3y)^2 = 9y^2 - 30y + 25  \tag 2$$ subbing $(2)$ in $(1)$ gives us $$(9y^2-30y+25)+ 4y^2-4(5-3y)+24y - 140 = 0$$ this simplifies to $$0=13y^2+6y-135= (y-3)(13y+45) $$

i hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 + y^2 + 3y - 5 + 6y - 35 = 0 \to x^2 = 40 - y^2 - 9y \to (5-3y)^2 = 4x^2 = 160 - 4y^2 - 36y \to 25 - 30y + 9y^2 = 160 - 4y^2 - 36y \to 13y^2 + 6y - 135 = 0$. Can you continue?